# Button not displayed in IE11

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

We recently upgraded our application from .net 2.0 to 4.5. As a result of which we had to use IE11. The problem I am facing is that certain buttons and an address which is in the Master Page in the application do not show up on the page display. It gets displayed only if I turn on Compatibility View which is not recommended. It uses a Css Class bluebutton which is being used by other buttons too and they are getting displayed on the page.
Below is the css class,
Hide   Copy Code

```css
input.bluebutton
{
   font-size:.875em;
   font-family:Arial;
   color:white;
   width:auto;
   height:22px;
   background: #606060 url(../../images/BlankBlueButton61x22RepeatX.gif) 0px 0px repeat-x scroll;
   border:1px none solid;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   padding: 0px 0.5em 0px 0.5em;
}
```

Below is the HTML tag of one of the pages,

```html
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSearch" runat="server" CssClass="bluebutton" CausesValidation="false"
                               meta:resourcekey="ButtonSearch" OnClick="ButtonSearchClick" />
```

Please let me know how do i go about this and get it working?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem 
the first was font-size with point value like 8.5p it never works
the second it was a property like this in the css 
`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient (GradientType=0,StartColorStr= 'buttonface' ,EndColorStr= 'oldlace' );`
i found the solution with internet explorer devlopper tool you select the div containing the button and start going down until you find it when you do just start activating and deactivationg the css properties until you find what you're looking for

Comment: The problem here is that the div in which the button is present itself is missing when checked in the developer tool.